# How to get count of a NSDictionary-stored NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I have a `NSDictionary` (parsed from JSON using `JSONObjectWithData`, if that's relevant) that looks like:

```
{
ids =     (
    49939999,
    44754859,
    14424892,
    16311801,
    16045487,
    31247745,
    5982852
);
"next_cursor" = 0;
"next_cursor_str" = 0;
"previous_cursor" = 0;
"previous_cursor_str" = 0;
}
```

when logged using `NSLog(@"%@", jsonResult);`.

I'm accessing ids with `friends = [jsonResult objectForKey:@"ids"];`, and would expect `friends` to be of type `NSArray`, but apparently it's of type `__NSCFArray`. Why?

I then try to get friends' size using `[friends count]` but this creates an exception when run.

How to get count of a NSDictionary-stored "NSArray"?

**UPDATE: Code**

```
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        id jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
        if (jsonResult != nil) {



            self.friends = [jsonResult objectForKey:@"ids"];

            NSLog(@"%@", self.friends);

            NSLog(@"%@", [self.friends class]);

            NSLog(@"%@", [self.friends count]);

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });                
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message?

Comment: The exception message is: `Thread 7, EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x258)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSCFArray is a subclass of NSArray. Most of the time when you deal with an NSArray, that's the concrete class you're dealing with. This is what it means in the documentation when it says NSArray is a class cluster.

Your crash is because when you try to print `[friends count]`, you use the format string `@"%@"`. `%@` tells NSLog to expect an object, but this is an NSUInteger. Instead, you should do `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[friends count])`. (If you're not entirely clear on the idea of format specifiers, Apple has a [handy guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).)

Comment: Just added the code. `friends` is defined in the header file with `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *friends;`

Answer (score 0):

`__NSCFArray` are just the underlying structure that both `NSArray` and `CFArray` use to support so-called toll-free bridging. Use use this:

```
NSArray *friends = (NSArray*)[jsonResult objectForKey:@"ids"];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.

Comment: What doesn't I change? If you test the type of `friends` it will still be of type `__NSCFArray` but that is the case for any `NSArray`. Using the code I supplied above, you can use `freinds` just as an ordinary array and it will work.

Comment: That cast literally does nothing.

Comment: It supresses a warning. There is no cast, rather an explicit declaration of the type. It makes the compiler and the IDE happy.

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen: What warning is it meant to suppress? `objectForKey:` returns `id`, which is compatible with any object type in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was stupid of myself. I just found out that `NSLog(@"%@")` only takes an object. You've got to specifically use `NSLog(@"%d")` to input an integer.

I'm not sure why this is not detected at compile-time, though.

Source: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog

Comment: It's not detected at compile time because to the language itself your format string is just a string — it doesn't mean anything special. It's the NSLog function itself that interprets the %@ specifier. Type checking a function like NSLog requires special compiler support. Fortunately, the necessary support was just recently added to LLVM, so expect it in Xcode sometime in the next year.

Comment: Sigh. Had you only stated that to begin with, rather than being hung up in the internal workings of core foundation. I'm glad you found a solution, but next time please supply the code line with the exception.